# Gre practice problem on Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

The [GRE Practice book](https://www.ets.org/s/gre/pdf/practice_book_math.pdf) includes this problem (#37).

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real vector space and let $P$
>   be a linear transformation of $V$ such that $P^2 = P$.
>   Which of the following must be true?
>
> I. $P$ is invertible.
>
> II. $P$ is diagonalizable.
>
> III. $P$ is either the identity transformation or the zero transformation.
>
> (A) None
>
> (B) I only
>
> (C) II only
>
> (D) III only
>
> (E) II and II

Here are my (modest) thoughts on the problem so far.

Choice I) Not necessarily true because $P$ could be the zero transformation.

Choice II) I really don't know anything about this. What is the significance of diagonalizable transformations?

Choice III) $P$ certainly could be the identity or zero transformations, but I don't know how to prove or disprove the existence of other valid $P$s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a transformation is called a projection. The only invertible projection is the identity: if $P^2=P$ and $P$ is invertible, then 
$$
P=P^{-1}P^2=P^{-1}P=I.
$$

A projection $P$ is always diagonalizable. Two ways I can see of seeing it: note that the eigenvalues of $P$ are $0$ and $1$ (unless $P=0$ or $P=I$, which are the easy cases).

- The decomposition $V=PV\oplus (I-P)V$ suggests that if you choose a basis of $V$ made of bases of $PV$ and $(I-P)V$, you will have a basis of eigenvectors.
- Alternatively, look at the Jordan form of $P$ and conclude that it has to be diagonal.

Nontrivial projections: here are infinitely many, in $M_2(\mathbb R)$:
$$
 \begin{bmatrix}t&\sqrt{t-t^2}\\\sqrt{t-t^2}&1-t\end{bmatrix},\ \ t\in[0,1]. 
$$
Or:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&x\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ x\in\mathbb R.
$$

Answer (score 0):

your thoughts on choice $1$ is right.

it always helps to cook up a few small examples satisfying the conditions, like

$$
 \begin{bmatrix}1& 1\\0 &0\end{bmatrix} 
$$

and

$$
 \begin{bmatrix}1& 0\\0 &0\end{bmatrix} 
$$